# FileUpload does not let me to save

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, webforms

I have a confusing problem. I'm trying to use FileUpload. The following code works well locally:

```
    var postedFile = uploader.PostedFile;
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    var newFile = Guid.NewGuid() + extension;
    var imageFilePath = Path.Combine(this.Server.MapPath("~/ProductImages"), newFile);
    uploader.SaveAs(imageFilePath);
```

But when I publish my code to my server in internet the following exception occurs:

> Could not find a part of the path *[...]*

When I change `uploader.SaveAs(imageFilePath);` to `uploader.SaveAs(imageFilePath.Replace(this.Request.ServerVariables["APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH"], "..\\"));`, this exception occurs:

> The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path *[..]* is not rooted.

Would any one tell me how to use an Uploader? And how I can solve this problem?

With thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem in your code. When you run an application over the a web server, web server manged by a user in OS.(for examle nobody for enginx or Application Pool group in IIS). 
You should set permission for folder that you want save the data. this my be done in your hosting file manager panel or via direct access to OS.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that local accounts aren't valid on remote resources on active directory - you need to connect as ComputerName$ or Anonymous depending on the type of local identity that you are using.

I was able to upload on debug mode but not on published site, so that might help you Mohammad.

Comment: Actually this is a server that hosts my app. I have no idea about its specification.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the folder ProductImages exists on the server?

You can try to call

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(this.Server.MapPath("~/ProductImages"))
```

before saving the file. It will create the directory if it doesn't exists or do nothing if it exists.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But :-( it didn't work. The exception is still occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem by setting the permission on the folder. I set the write permission on "**Application pool group**" for that folder and now I can upload any file there, by my app.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try this one.. for uploading and insert the values in database..

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/" + filename));
                Stream str = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;             
                        con.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmds = new SqlCommand("insert into datas(name,path,types,pricing)values(@name,@path,@types,@pricing)", con);
                        cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",d);
                        cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", filename);
                        cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@types", RadioButton1.Text);
                        cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pricing", "FineGrained");
                        cmds.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('successfully uploaded');</script>");
```